# Possible race-condition/undefined behaviour in multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, c++11

I've written a multi-threaded test program to test my DB server but it seems like I'm hitting some kind of race-condition/undefined behaviour scenario.

My program uses `'n'` number of threads to enter `'x'` number of records(IMSIs) in the database. In the threads, I fetch the value of the IMSI(to be entered in the DB), and then call the API which inserts the IMSI into the DB. Although, I'm not getting any errors in the 'Insert' API, still, not all IMSIs are being inserted in the DB!

Here's the program:

```
 #include"DB.hpp"
 #include<thread>
 #include<vector>
 #include<string>
 #include<mutex>        
 #include<algorithm>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 std::mutex mtx_imsi;
 std::mutex mtx_errorCount;
 std::mutex mtx_addImsi;

 class data
 {
    public:
    static int64_t imsi; //This is stored in the DB
    static int64_t no_of_threads;
    static int64_t no_of_subscribers; //No. of Imsis that will be stored.
    static int64_t error_count; //No. of IMSIs which couldn't be written.
    static vector<string> imsi_list;

    static void get_imsi(int64_t &l_imsi)
    {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_imsi);

        if(imsi==405862999999999+no_of_subscribers)
           l_imsi=-1;           
        else
           l_imsi=++imsi;
    }

    static void add_count(int64_t l_count)
    {
       std::lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_errorCount);
       error_count+=l_count;
    }

    static void add_imsi(vector<string>& list)
    {
       std::lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_addImsi);
       for(const auto& x:list)
           imsi_list.push_back(x);
    }
};

int64_t data::imsi(405862999999999); //This is the initial value
int64_t data::no_of_threads;
int64_t data::no_of_subscribers;
int64_t data::error_count=0;
vector<string> data::imsi_list;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Error in input parameters"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<argv[0]<<"[No_of_threads]   [No_of_subscribers]  [NODE_IP]"<<endl;
        cout<<"e.g. "<<argv[0]<<"10 200000 10.32.129.66"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    data::no_of_threads=stoi(argv[1]);
    data::no_of_subscribers=stoi(argv[2]);

    DB::InitDBConnection(argv[3]);   //This will initialise the DB connection with the IP

    vector<thread> t;

    for(int i=0;i<data::no_of_threads;i++)
    {
        thread th([&]{
            int64_t errorCount=0,temp_imsi; 
            vector<string> temp_list;

            data::get_imsi(temp_imsi);

            while(temp_imsi!=-1)
            {
                string l_imsi=to_string(temp_imsi);                                             
                temp_list.push_back(l_imsi);

                ReturnCode status=DB::rtInsertImsi(l_imsi);

                if(status!=INSERT_OK)
                    ++errorCount;

                data::get_imsi(temp_imsi);
            }

            data::add_count(errorCount);
            data::add_imsi(temp_list);

        });

        t.push_back(move(th));        
    }

    for(auto &x:t)
    x.join();

    std::sort (data::imsi_list.begin(), data::imsi_list.end());
    cout<<endl<<"IMSI LIST"<<endl;

    // Printing the IMSIs which were entered.
    for(const auto&x:data::imsi_list)
        cout<<x<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<"Number of Imsis used: "<<data::imsi-405862999999999;
    cout<<endl<<"Number of errors: "<<data::error_count;

    return 0;
}
```

At this moment, I believe that there's nothing wrong with my 'Insert' function(which I'm calling inside the thread), because it's used in other multi-threaded programs with no such behavior. What might be the reason behind some IMSIs not being inserted? Is there anything wrong with this main program?

---

While posting this question, I had modified the actual code in order to make the code more understandable (I didn't know I would be removing the lines containing the bug). Now, I've realized my mistake. In my actual code, I don't pass the Imsi obtained from get_imsi() to my insert function (which would have been thread safe), instead, I use the value obtained to fill a data structure and pass that data structure to the insert function. As I was not filling the data structure in a thread safe manner I got the observations I've mentioned.

I want to delete the question but due to the running bounty I can't do it anymore!

---

Comment: If there's data you're passing to `DB::rtInsertImsi` that's not showing up in the database, then how could is possibly be the code you've shown us that's at fault?

Comment: btw, you check that `argc` is `3`, but then you initialize the connection with `argv[3]` (aka [null](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)), is this intended? (woops, just saw the edit)

Comment: That's one another mistake! Please ignore.

Comment: This is one of the more misdesigned programs I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program, as it is written, has many problems. But race conditions and other such thread nastiness are not among them

Public static class variables are a very bad idea. They're basically just scoped global variables. And most of them don't change after they're initialized. They should be `const` member variables.

Maybe if you had designed your program more carefully and cleanly at the start, you wouldn't have made the mistake you had such a hard time spotting later.

Here is how this could've been written better. I've faithfully replicated most of what you did. I don't know enough about what you're doing to do anything better than that:

```
//#include "DB.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class data
{
 public:
   data(int64_t no_of_threads, int64_t no_of_subscribers, int64_t starting_imsi)
        : no_of_threads_(no_of_threads), no_of_subscribers_(no_of_subscribers),
          starting_imsi_(starting_imsi),
          error_count_(0),
          cur_imsi_(0)
   {
      cur_imsi_ = starting_imsi;
   }

   int64_t next_imsi() {
      if ((cur_imsi_ - starting_imsi_) >= no_of_subscribers_) {
         return -1;
      } else {
         return ++cur_imsi_;
      }
   }

   void add_errors(int64_t l_count)
   {
      lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_error_count_);
      error_count_ += l_count;
   }

   void add_imsi_list(vector<string> const & list)
   {
      lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_imsi_list_);
      imsi_list_.insert(imsi_list_.end(), list.begin(), list.end());
   }

   void sort_imsi_list()
   {
      // Probably not necessary, but to be thorough.
      lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_imsi_list_);
      sort(imsi_list_.begin(), imsi_list_.end());
   }

   int64_t imsis_used() const { return cur_imsi_ - starting_imsi_; }

   int64_t error_count() const {
      lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_error_count_);
      return error_count_;
   }

   int64_t thread_count() const { return no_of_threads_; }

   vector<string> const &get_imsi_list() const { return imsi_list_; }

 private:
   const int64_t no_of_threads_;
   const int64_t no_of_subscribers_;
   const int64_t starting_imsi_;
   atomic<int64_t> cur_imsi_;

   mutable mutex mtx_error_count_; // Never const
   int64_t error_count_; //No. of IMSIs which couldn't be written.
   mutable mutex mtx_imsi_list_; // Never const
   vector<string> imsi_list_;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc != 3)
   {
      cout << endl << "Error in input parameters" << endl;
      cout << endl << argv[0]
           << "[No_of_threads]   [No_of_subscribers]  [NODE_IP]" << endl;
      cout << "e.g. " << argv[0] << "10 200000 10.32.129.66" << endl;
      return 1;
   }

   data imsi_generator(stoi(argv[1]), stoi(argv[2]), 405862999999999);

   // DB::InitDBConnection(argv[3]);   //This will initialise the DB connection with the IP

   vector<thread> t;

   for(int i=0;i<imsi_generator.thread_count();i++)
   {
      t.emplace_back([&imsi_generator]
                     {
                        int64_t errorCount = 0, temp_imsi;
                        vector<string> temp_list;

                        temp_imsi = imsi_generator.next_imsi();

                        while (temp_imsi != -1)
                        {
                           string const l_imsi = to_string(temp_imsi);
                           temp_list.push_back(l_imsi);

                           // ReturnCode status = DB::rtInsertImsi(l_imsi);
                           //
                           // if (status != INSERT_OK)
                           //    ++errorCount;

                           temp_imsi = imsi_generator.next_imsi();
                        }

                        imsi_generator.add_errors(errorCount);
                        imsi_generator.add_imsi_list(temp_list);
                     });
   }

   for (auto &x : t)
      x.join();

   imsi_generator.sort_imsi_list();
   cout << endl << "IMSI LIST" << endl;

   // Printing the IMSIs which were entered.
   for (auto const &x : imsi_generator.get_imsi_list())
      cout << x << endl;

   cout << endl << "Number of Imsis used: " << imsi_generator.imsis_used();
   cout << endl << "Number of errors: " << imsi_generator.error_count();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll be grateful if you can highlight some more problems(if any) other than the public static class variables that you have mentioned.

Comment: @VishalSharma - At some point I'll tackle re-writing what you wrote into something more reasonable and manageable. Hopefully that will be within a day or two.

Comment: Haha..I think I have seriously messed up here... Thanks anyways

Comment: @VishalSharma - There, I've posted a new version that's a partial rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see which compiler you are using, however with Clang and GCC on Linux and Mac, you have the option to activate the sanitizers.

Looking at the comments, I recommend creating different flavors of builds to check different kind of issues. [`-fsanitize=thread`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) will activate the thread sanitizer. If you test your program, it should inform you about race conditions at the lowest level. It even reports them when they don't actually trigger in that run. Really useful!

When triggered, it gives you callstacks of the access and of the launching of the thread. As well as the variable this is about.

An easy solution to solve this is by making the variable atomic, however, be warned, that doesn't solve the logical problem. So look closely to what is actually going on and fix the bigger issue at end.

Other sanitizers include checking for undefined behavior, incorrect memory access ...

Comment: I keep forgetting to use the sanitizers. They're nifty.